# show that a normed vector space $(V,\Vert . \Vert)$ can become a metric space

Tags: linear-algebra, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

with a distance defined by:

$d(x,y) = \Vert (x-y)\Vert$

I know that

> Every normed space is a metric space, but not the other way round

and:

> Metric spaces are much more general than normed spaces

and:

> the principles that distinguish a norm from a metric are 
>   1) translation invariance and 2) homogeneity.

At this point what I have to write formally?

thanks

Comment: You need to verify that your $d$ satisfies the axioms for a metric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a matter of noticing that:

- $d(x,y)=0\iff\|x-y\|=0\iff x=y$.
- $d(y,x)=\|y-x\|=\|(-1)\times(y-x)\|=|-1|.\|x-y\|=\|x-y\|$;
- $d(x,z)=\|x-z\|=\|x-y+y-z\|\leqslant\|x-y\|+\|y-z\|=d(x,y)+d(y,z)$.

Comment: and $d(x,y)= 0 \implies ||x-y|| = 0 \implies x-y = 0 \implies x=y$

Comment: @Max I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Is it all? So every normed vector space can be metric so that a norm always induces a distance by $d(x,y) = \Vert (x-y) \Vert , right?

Comment: @stefanoferrari It's up to you to tell us if that's all. What else do you want to prove?

Comment: I thought It was more difficult. Thanks for the help!